# Formatear numbero con puntos miles

Tags: java

Quería saber como formar el  numero 132.522,21 , con los puntos en los miles y la coma para decimales.

Que tipo de primitivo es mejor para hacerlo?

Comment: Ningún primitivo numérico tiene contador de miles. Tienes que meterselo tu manualmente transformando el numero a String

Comment: Y que has intentado para que no lo consigas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu amigo es [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Haz algo así:

```
double num = 132522.21;
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");

System.out.println(formatter.format(num));
```

El resultado es: **132.522,21**

Comment: funciona perfecto agrega punto y coma a una Cantidad...gracias